# How to make screen readers read a notification when a table's content changes?

Tags: javascript, frontend, wai-aria

I have a table in my HTML, and its content changes dynamically.

I would like to make the screen reader read a notification everytime the table's content changes, could anyone tell me how to do it?

I tried 3 ways but none of them is ideal:

1. Adding `aria-live="polite"` to the whole table. Then the content of the WHOLE table will be read, which is too much. I only want to anounce a short notification, like one sentence.
2. Creating an invisible `div`, placing it in position `left = -1000px` or so, add `aria-live="polite"` to it, and in JS, I changed its text, which is the notification to be read, everytime the table content changes, like `d3.select('#report-table-updated-aria-notification').text("Report table updated");`. But this way the notification will only be read ONCE, because  the JS uses the same string to replace the previous one, meaning the text is not changed, so the `aria-live="polite"` is not triggered.
3. Adding `role="alert"` to the invisible `div` mentioned above. This time the notification is read everytime the table content changes, but the sentence is prefixed by "Alert", for example, "Alert: this is a notification". But I don't want the word of "Alert" to be read since this is not an alert.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just had an idea. You mentioned that you made a hidden div, but that it only read once. What would happen if you used the JS .remove() function after it was read, and then re-added it when needed. For example:

```html
<div id="test" aria-live="polite" style="display:none;">Some Important Text</div>
```

```js
function someFunction(text){
     //remove the element
     document.getElementById('test').remove();

     //re-add the element to the DOM
     document.body.innerHTML += `<div id="test" aria-live="polite" 
     style="display:none;">`+text+`</div>`;
}
//you can call someFunction(New Text) to change the content
```

Comment: I tried to set the text to `""` right after setting it to the sentence, which is the same idea as yours I think, but it doesn't work. I figured out a very hacky way to do that, which is to check if the text is the default one. If yes, we need to alter it, and I do that by adding a period at the end. If not, meaning the sentence already has a period attached, then we are good. It works though very silly. Thank you for your help anyway! (BTW, you cannot use `style="display:none;"`, because this way it will not be read under any circumstances)

Comment: Thanks for the info, @powerseed! Changing the text to "" is a bit different than completely removing the item from the DOM, I'd recommend testing this approach, I believe it could work!